# Python help, reading and writing to a txt file

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have posted the relevant part of my code below. Before that are just load functions, which I am pretty sure have no errors.

I am recieving error

```
IndexError: list index out of range( "namestaj["Naziv"] = deon[1]")
```

Does anyone see something out of order?

```
#load furniture from a txt file
def ucitajNamestaj():
    listaNamestaja = open("namestaj.txt", "r").readlines()
    namestaj = []
    for red in listaNamestaja:
        namestaj.append(stringToNamestaj(red))
    return namestaj

#String to Furniture, dictionary
def stringToNamestaj(red):
    namestaj = {}
    deon = red.strip().split("|")
    namestaj["Sifra"] = deon[0]
    namestaj["Naziv"] = deon[1]
    namestaj["Boja"] = deon[2]
    namestaj["Kolicina"] = int(deon[3])
    namestaj["Cena"] = float(deon[4])
    namestaj["Kategorija"] = deon[5]
    namestaj["Dostupan"] = deon[6]
    return namestaj
```

Comment: Please  format your code, it is very difficult to read and impossible to spot any indentation errors.  Your line `deon = red.strip().split("|") ` is probably not producing more than one element (maybe a blank line in the file?).  Print the value of `deon` after this statement to check.  We can't reproduce this without your data file.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things first, try always to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make sure you use properly the SO code directives, otherwise your question is unreadable.

Now, probably what's happening is your file has some empty lines and you're not skipping those, try this:

```
def ucitajNamestaj(): 
    listaNamestaja = open("namestaj.txt", "r").readlines() 
    namestaj = [] 
    for red in listaNamestaja:
        if red.strip() == "":
            continue
        namestaj.append(stringToNamestaj(red)) 
    return namestaj

def stringToNamestaj(red):
    namestaj = {}
    deon = red.strip().split("|")
    namestaj["Sifra"] = deon[0]
    namestaj["Naziv"] = deon[1]
    namestaj["Boja"] = deon[2]
    namestaj["Kolicina"] = int(deon[3])
    namestaj["Cena"] = float(deon[4])
    namestaj["Kategorija"] = deon[5]
    namestaj["Dostupan"] = deon[6]
    return namestaj
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeh im amazed how i didnt see it sooner